# Dynamicaly generate links in view in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a string like

> my beutifull super %url%URLLINK%url% with no doorway!

and I'd like to get something like that:

```
my beutifull super <a (click)="urlHandler(URLLINK)">URLLINK</a> with no doorway!
```

How can I dynamicaly generate template elements in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome Bob Balkonsky!

We can put this functionality into a separate component,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-string-transformer',
  template: `{{parsed.before || ''}}<a *ngIf="parsed.url" (click)="handleUrlClick(parsed.url)">{{parsed.url}}</a>{{parsed.after || ''}}`,
  styles: [`a { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;}`]
})
export class StringTransformerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() str: string
  @Output() onUrlClicked: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  parsed: ParsedString = {} as ParsedString

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.parsed = this._parseStr(this.str)

  }

  _parseStr(str: string): ParsedString {
    const [full, before, url, after] = str.match(/(.*)%url%(.+)%url%(.*)/)
    return {before, url, after}
  }

  handleUrlClick(url: string): void {
    this.onUrlClicked.emit(url);
  }
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nakjdb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstring-transformer.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, I gave it demo my best shot

Comment: Not sure why it's getting down voted, seems a neat solution. Maybe a bit too much code / not enough explanation for the problem at hand?

Comment: @qiAlex in short, there can be a lot of links, so I changed the source code a bit (made the regular expression lazy and output into the child component only 'before' and the 'url' parts), but the task is solved, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [innerHTML]:
TS:

```
 url = `my beutifull super <a style="cursor:pointer" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/">URLLINK</a> with no doorway!`
```

HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="url"></div>
```

example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ah7dd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: `[innerHTML]` can easily introduce security problems

Comment: @bartosztermena it would be a good option if you needed a normal link, but as I wrote, you need to process the clicks through a function and [routerlink] it won't work that way either.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split the text on %url% and assemble the parts in your template:

ts:

```
//Create array to hold parts of string
linkText: string[] = [];

//Split your string on %url% delimiter to get start text, url and end text as separate strings
  ngOnInit()
  {
    let myUrl = 'my beutifull super %url%URLLINK%url% with no doorway!';
    this.linkText  = myUrl.split('%url%');
  }
```

html:

```
//build text and link using array
<p>{{linkText[0]}}<a (click)="urlHandler(linkText[1])">{{linkText[1]}}</a>{{linkText[2]}}</p>
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clauib)

Comment: in case of `myUrl` = `%url%URLLINK%url%` there will be inconsistent spaces around link

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: `{{linkText[0]}} <a` - there should not be a space between `}}` and `<a`. and also between `a>` and `{{`

Comment: Got you, spaces removed : )

Comment: @jmp if the source text has a different order of parts (e.g. a link at the beginning of a line) or multiple links, this example will not work

Comment: True, but your question asked for solution for a specific order for single link. I would have extended if you had said it needed to work for different patterns etc. @qiAlex did give a nice extended solution.